# How to extract value from json response in postman, whose value has string and integer

Tags: postman

For JSON Response

`"@id": "/api/companies/6"`

I want to get only id '6' from the value "/api/companies/6" and set it as environmental variable. Can any one help me with this?

I have used the below script to extract the id but it extract the string "/api/companies/6" . I want to extract only the integer '6'

`pm.environment.set("CompanyId", jsonData["@id"]);`

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like the following:

```
var jsonData = pm.response.json();
var idStr = jsonData["@id];
var id = idStr.substr(idStr.length - 1);
pm.environment.set("CompanyId", id);
```

It can probably be consolidated into fewer lines but wanted to show you the flow of extracting and setting the character(s) you want.